# React Native: Set React Navigation's Screens Headers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, mobile

I want to have the tabs from BottomTabsNavigator and the header from StackNavigator in the case of jwt = true.

Do someone know how can I do it?

You can find my navigation jsx below.

If I didn't give sufficient details, please ask me.

Thank you.

```
<NavigationContainer>
  {jwt ? (
    <Bottom.Navigator>
      <Bottom.Screen
        name="ToDoList"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          title: "Not To Do List",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }: any) => (
            <Icon name="check" color={color} size={28} />
          ),
        }}
      />

      <Bottom.Screen
        name="NotToDoList"
        component={NotToDo}
        options={{
          title: "To Do List",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }: any) => (
            <FIcon name="ban" color={color} size={28} />
          ),
        }}
      />

      <Bottom.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={Profile}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }: any) => (
            <FIcon name="user" color={color} size={28} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Bottom.Navigator>
  ) : (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="SignIn"
        component={SignIn}
        options={{ ...centerTitle("Sign In"), headerLeft }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="SignUp"
        component={SignUp}
        options={{ ...centerTitle("Sign Up"), headerLeft }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )}
</NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: So the conditional rendering of `jwt` looks fine. Do you want a layout where you have both tabs and the stack header, but only if `jwt` is true? What do you want to render if `jwt` is `false`?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain too well. So I want to have the Stack Header in Bottom Tabs, Bottom is createBottomTabNavigator for having bottom tabs like on Instagram, but it don't have the classic Header from createStackNavigator. Is there anyway to have the Header from a createStackNavigator Route on a createBottomTabNavigator Route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the header of a stack navigator for the screens of your bottom tab navigator you can nest your tab navigator inside another stack navigator.

This is the general structure you could apply:

```
NavigationContainer
...MainNavigator (StackNavigator): show if `jwt`
......BottomNavigator (TabNavigator and Screen of MainNavigator)
...LoginNavigator (StackNavigator) show if not `jwt`
```

I've made a more general reproducible example to illustrate the point:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

const Main = createStackNavigator();
const Login = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const Screen1 = () => {
  return <Text>Screen1</Text>;
};

const Screen2 = () => {
  return <Text>Screen1</Text>;
};

const LoginPage = () => {
  return <Text>LoginPage</Text>;
};

function TabNavigator() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

function MainNavigator() {
  return (
    <Main.Navigator>
      <Main.Screen name="Tabs" component={TabNavigator} />
    </Main.Navigator>
  );
}

function LoginNavigator() {
  return (
    <Login.Navigator>
      <Login.Screen name="Login" component={LoginPage} />
    </Login.Navigator>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  const jwt = true; // in your case this value is dynamic of course
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {jwt ? <MainNavigator /> : <LoginNavigator />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Update**

If you want the name of the stack navigator header to be the same as the screen names you have in your tab navigator or if you want the name to be dynamic in another way based on the tab names we can use the `getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute` that react navigation provides.

*getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute is imported from @react-navigation/native just as `NavigationContainer` is.*

```
// First we create a function like this:
function getHeaderTitle(route) {
  // In case the focused route is not found, assume it's the first screen, Screen1 in this example.
  return getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route) ?? 'Screen1';
}

// Then we can use it like this:
function MainNavigator() {
  return (
    <Main.Navigator>
      <Main.Screen
        options={({route}) => ({
          headerTitle: getHeaderTitle(route),
        })}
        name="Tabs"
        component={TabNavigator}
      />
    </Main.Navigator>
  );
}
```

You can read about it here in the documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options-resolution/#setting-parent-screen-options-based-on-child-navigators-state.

Comment: It works! But I have the title "Tabs" in every page, how can I custom them?

Comment: Currently the title is set based on the `name` prop of the screen inside `MainNavigator`. Do you want the title of the header to be the current active tab? If so I've updated the answer to show how you could go about making the title dynamic based on the child route names (The tab navigator screen names in this example).

Comment: I added it. I wanted to be based on the name, but I added a function for putting space before every upper case character except the first one. Thanks so much for help!!! I couldn't have done this alone.